# Typescript filter returning empty list

Tags: angularjs, typescript, aurelia, typescript2.0

I am trying to filter an array in typescript and aurelia however I only ever get empty lists.

If i have the key word of `ra` and search on the `firstName` property i expect to have the first object (with name of "Raja") returned. I dont understand what I am missing?

Below is an array of `contact` objects.

```
let contacts = [
  {
    id:getId(),
    firstName:"Raja",
    lastName:"Mani",
    email:"rmani@gmail.com",
    phoneNumber:"408-973-5050",
    birthDate: new Date(1973, 5, 1)
  },
  {
    id:getId(),
    firstName:"Jhansi",
    lastName:"Rani",
    email:"jrani@gmail.com",
    phoneNumber:"867-5309",
    birthDate: new Date(1970, 5, 24)
  },
  {
    id:getId(),
    firstName:"Aditi",
    lastName:"Raja",
    email:"araja@gmail.com",
    phoneNumber:"408-973-9006",
    birthDate: new Date(2001, 10, 12)
  }        
];
```

These objects are have the interface IContact

```
export interface IContact {
    id: number;
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    email: string;
    phoneNumber: string;
    birthDate: Date;
}
```

And this is my filter query

```
let results = contacts.filter((c: IContact) => ((c.firstName.indexOf(keyword) !== -1)));
```

Comment: indexOf is case sensitive: "Raja".indexOf('ra') === -1 / "Raja".indexOf('Ra') === 0

Comment: what does this have to do with angularjs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As `indexOf` is case sensitive you need transform both case before comparing:

```
c.firstName.toUpperCase().indexOf(keyword.toUpperCase()) !== -1
```